# React devtools automatically triggering debugger

Tags: css, reactjs, web, mern, react-devtools

I have just changed some code in my react component and saved to check those changes in browser.
But when I am going to browser then debugger is automatically getting triggered wheras I haven't used debugger in my whole codebase.

This is what I am getting in the browser:
[image]

Comment: Seems like something that could happen globally. I've encountered it today during development as well

Comment: How did you fixed that? Exactly I encountered it for the first time today

Comment: Frankly I just got rid of errors in my code. I was thinking it was related to my code back then - it seems now it's not

Answer (score 1):

The `debugger` trigger has been shipped by mistake in the last 24 hours
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308
you have to wait for a new version and disable it in the meantime

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @Riccardo!!